# how to integrate kendo licensed files in angular 5 app?

Tags: kendo-ui, angular5, kendo-ui-angular2

We have an angular 5 app developed using angular-cli tool. We were using kendo trial version until now. Now, we would like to replace it with kendo licensed files.

For trial version we had installed kendo components using npm. So all of the kendo dependencies are in package.json file.

For licensed files, we downloaded them from telerik site after getting license.
Now how do we replace those trial files with licensed files in our angular-cli project?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I will assume you are talking about Kendo UI for Angular and not Kendo UI for jQuery or any other Kendo.*

You install packages with npm, same as for trial.

Notes:

- For getting source code, you will need to enter credentials. [Documentation](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/installation/source-code/).
- License information [here](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/blob/master/LICENSE.md).

> If you do not own a commercial license, this file shall be governed by
>   the trial license terms.

- Read [this issue](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/712) for details. I think it will answer all your questions.